# how to attach .ics file with email in node js?

Tags: node.js, email, sendgrid

I am using ics for calender for get event it done successfully but i want to send some text with `.ics` attachment and for that i try this code just see and tell me where i have to change.
I got event.ics file but want to send that file with mail text/html content.

```
var ics = require('ics');
var options = {
    eventName: 'Fingerpainting lessons',
    filename: 'event1.ics',
    dtstart: date,
    location: 'Here and there',
    email: {
        name: 'alex bob',
        email: email
    }
};
ics.createEvent(options, null, function(err, calendar) {
    if (!err)
    {
            console.log('Event file',calendar);
            var filePath = path.join('vabo_email', 'email.html');
                fs.readFile(filePath, {encoding: 'utf-8'},
                function(err, data) {
                        if ( ! err )
                        {

                            var helper = require('sendgrid').mail;

                            from_email = new helper.Email('booking@callvabo.com')
                            to_email = new helper.Email(email)
                            subject = subject
                            //Dynamic content
                            var data = data.replace("$content", bodycontent)

                            content = new helper.Content('text/html', data)
                            //content = new helper.Content("text/Calendar",calendar)
                            mail = new helper.Mail(from_email, subject, to_email,content);

                            var sg = require('sendgrid')('secretekey');

                            var requestBody = mail.toJSON();
                            var request = sg.emptyRequest();
                            request.method = 'POST';
                            request.path = '/v3/mail/send';
                            request.body = requestBody;
                            data = new helper.Content("text/Calendar",calendar)
                            request.attachments = [{'filename': 'calendar.ics', 'content': data}]

                            sg.API(request, function (error, response) {
                                if ( ! error )
                                {
                                        console.log('mail send Successfully to',email);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                        console.log('Error for send mail',error);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                console.log('Error for calendar',err);
                        }
                        });
    }
    else
    {
            console.log('Error for creating Event',err);
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks @Justin Steele

Comment: I'm still working on this too. I can't seem to get attachments at the moment either...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

calendar only contains the file path and name. You need to read in the file contents and then you need to Base64 encode the file content And finally request.attachments isn't correct. Add the attachments to the mail object or requestBody.

```
mail = new helper.Mail(from_email, subject, to_email,content);
var base64Content = fs.readFileSync(calendar).toString('base64');
mail.attachments = [{'filename': 'calendar.ics', 'content': base64Content, 'type': 'text/Calendar'}]

var sg = require('sendgrid')('secretekey');

var requestBody = mail.toJSON();
var request = sg.emptyRequest();
request.method = 'POST';
request.path = '/v3/mail/send';
request.body = requestBody;

sg.API(request, function (error, response) {
```

Comment: Thanks @Justin Steele

Comment: still i can not send file as attachment

Comment: @Alex, try the above changes. This finally worked for me.

Comment: but i got calendar before content ,